# Pipeline resource triggers doesn't consider branch

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I've two Azure DevOps CI pipelines

1. DataPipeline\Windows - Build
2. DataPipeline\TestPipeline

The second pipeline is a pipeline resource trigger. I've used [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers) as a reference.

When a pull request is created (e.g. with *dev* branch as source branch and *main* branch as target branch, not merged yet) both these pipelines are triggered (by default configuration). The second pipeline may pick up old artefacts (this is a different part altogether). A second run for pipeline DataPipeline\TestPipeline is triggered automatically as soon as DataPipeline\Windows - Build completes for a commit in the *dev* branch. Is this possible? I've specified the branch name in the resources trigger. Is something wrong with the YAML configuration?

My expected behaviour is when a pull request is created for branch name: xyz (not main), DataPipeline\TestPipeline shouldn't be triggered again after DataPipeline\Windows - Build completes.

DataPipeline\TestPipeline.yml

```
 trigger: none
    resources:
      pipelines:
      - pipeline: DataPipeline
        source: 'DataPipeline\Windows - Build'
        branch: main
        trigger:
           branches:
             include:
             - main
    
    name: TestPipeline_$(variable)
    
    jobs:
    // template based job
```